# static queue and dynamic extensions

Tags: sql-server, debian, asterisk, crm, sip

I use the odbc function and get the number of the manager from the MSSQL table if the client calls me a second or more times.

```
[incoming_calls]
exten => s,1,Set(fname=${CDR(uniqueid)})
exten=>  s,2,Set(extext=${ODBC_GET_EXTEN(${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => s,3,Dial(SIP/${extext})
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

But if a client calls me the first time, the call must have got the manager according to the queue.

How can I combine a queue and a dynamic function? Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use goto and label. It works.

```
[incoming_calls]
exten => s,1,Set(fname=${CDR(uniqueid)})
exten => s,2,Set(extext=${ODBC_GET_EXTEN(${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => s,3,GotoIf($[${extext}!=""]?ee:qq)
exten => s,4(qq),Queue(queue2228) ;
exten => s,4(ee),Dial(SIP/${extext})
exten => s,5,Hangup()
```